# Запятая после междометия (перед "как")

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, междометие

Из учебника Валгиной:
"Междометия, стоящие перед словами **как, какой**, в сочетании с ними выражающие высокую степень качества, запятой не отделяются: **Ух как я устал; Ах какой сердитый**".

Я думала, что это правило распространяется на следующие предложения:
**1. Ох, как тяжело, душно как.

2. Как я люблю море, ах, как я люблю море.**

Однако после междометия перед "как" стоит запятая.
С чем это связано? Здесь нет высокой степени качества?

Comment: Из какого источника 2 последних примера?

Comment: **Ох, как голова горит! <…> Пойду, погуляю. Ох, как тяжело, душно как!** (А. Н. Островский.  Не было ни гроша, да вдруг алтын) http://rulibrary.ru/ostrovsky/ne_bylo_ni_grosha,_da_vdrug_altyn/31   **Как я люблю море, ах, как я люблю море!** (А. П. Чехов. Рассказы. Повести. 1894-1897)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Розенталя  приводятся оба варианта:

**1) Междометие:** ***Ах, какие*** это были ночи! (Гарш.)

**2) Частица:** Собственность, значит, признаёт; а это, по нынешнему времени, ***ах как приятно***!

Выбор делается **по значению и структуре (интонации)  предложения.**

Междометие обособляется, а частица входит в сочетание и произносится без паузы, на нее падает логическое ударение.

Междометие выражает чувство, а частица усиливает значение, обозначая высокую степень признака.

**В приведенных предложениях более удобна интонация, соответствующая обособлению междометия:**

Ох, как тяжелО, дУшно как.
2. КАк я люблю море, Ах, кАк я люблю море.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128